# Can I use a group in a root domain to filter application of a group policy object from this root domain for a computer in a child domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, group-policy

- I have a root domain (lets call it root.local) with a child domain (lets call it child.root.local).
- now I have a Group Policy object in the root domain, e.g. GPO_root
- in the child domain I have a computer, computer_child. Is is located in the child domain in the OU child.root.local/OU_child_computers.
- In the root domain I also have a group of the type Security / Domain Local, named computer_group_root, which contains computer_child as a member.
- Now I have linked GPO_root to child.root.local/OU_child_computers
- I have also edited the Delegation /Permissions of GPO_root, removing the permission "Apply" for "Authenticated users" and adding it for "computer_group_root".

However, this does not seem to work. If I run "gpresult /scope computer /r" on , I see:

`The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out

```
GPO_root
    Filtering:  Denied (Security)`
```

So GPO_root does not get applied.

If I edit the permissions of GPO_root and directly give the computer account computer_child the "Apply" permission, it works. But if I just use computer_group_root it doesn't. (By the way, this construct works without problems if all the objects are in the same domain, I have used it this way many times.)

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. Can I  get it to work using a group?
3. How?

(the real-world scenario is of course a little more complex, with multiple computers and child domains. I want to avoid having to add permissions for all computers directly, also having to remember to update the GPO permissions every time a new computer is added to said group. So I'd like to use a group.)